# Sluggish Asset Indexing

Tags: entries, assets, performance

Craft is a miracle for us but we've hit a snag.

We have about 100 products with around 10 images each.

We've scraped the images from the old site and put them into the appropriately named folders in assets.

Each time we add more, we have to run the asset reindexer which will only reindex the entire section. So even if we add a single folder of images, the entire lot are indexed again. If you've ever used the asset indexer you'll know that for whatever reason it is dog slow.

Why is this?
Could the immediate folder not be quickly indexed when the asset viewer is opened in the back end or at least provide an option to reindex that specific entrys assets?

Future projects may have 10,000 assets+ so it is a concern.

I'm open to better workflow suggestions as well.

Thanks :)

Comment: I had a similar issue. Check out my question here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/update-asset-index-in-batches.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! Perhaps stackexchange was inappropriate but I was really looking for a conversation about how this could be better integrated in vanilla craftcms. The answer "write a plugin" is not really a great answer.

Comment: "Each time we add more" - if you're adding them through Craft, you don't need to re-index them every time.

Comment: I see what you're saying. It would be nice to have some kind of quick index button in the gallery view. It would only index the parent content. The issue is that after a considerable time sometimes my VM just dies and the asset index stops dead which is why the "batches" issue exists. The workflow for this needs to be better.

Comment: Sounds like your bouncing into resource limits, Jake. Are you able to bump processor and RAM resources?

Comment: Brad is right... Why are you not simply uploading new images through the Craft UI?

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around this is to create a new Asset Source (let’s call it “Staging”).

1. Add the folder of unindexed images/assets into *Staging*, our new asset source (which should otherwise be empty).
2. Now, run the asset indexer via Settings > Update Asset Indexes only for our new source, *Staging*.
3. Once the indexer has done its job, go to the Assets section of the Control Panel and drag the freshly indexed folder of images/assets from *Staging* to the desired Asset Source.

Repeat the above process every time you wish to index a bunch of new assets without touching the previously indexed assets.